# How to aggregate string to dictionary like results in pyspark?

Tags: string, aggregation

I have a dataframe and I want to aggregate to daily.

```
data = [
    (125, '2012-10-10','good'),
    (20, '2012-10-10','good'),
    (40, '2012-10-10','bad'),
    (60, '2012-10-10','NA')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["temperature", "date","performance"])
```

I could aggregate numerical  values using spark built in functions like max, min, avg. How could I aggregate strings?

I expect something like:

| date | max_temp | min_temp | performance_frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-10-10 | 125 | 20 | "good": 2, "bad":1, "NA":1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use MapType and UDF with Counter to return the value counts,

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import MapType,StringType,IntegerType
from collections import Counter

data = [(125, '2012-10-10','good'),(20, '2012-10-10','good'),(40, '2012-10-10','bad'),(60, '2012-10-10','NA')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["temperature", "date","performance"])

udf1 = F.udf(lambda x: dict(Counter(x)),MapType(StringType(),IntegerType()))

df.groupby('date').agg(F.min('temperature'),F.max('temperature'),udf1(F.collect_list('performance')).alias('performance_frequency')).show(1,False)
+----------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
|date      |min(temperature)|max(temperature)|performance_frequency            |
+----------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+
|2012-10-10|20              |125             |Map(NA -> 1, bad -> 1, good -> 2)|
+----------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+

df.groupby('date').agg(F.min('temperature'),F.max('temperature'),udf1(F.collect_list('performance')).alias('performance_frequency')).collect()
[Row(date='2012-10-10', min(temperature)=20, max(temperature)=125, performance_frequency={'bad': 1, 'good': 2, 'NA': 1})]
```

Hope this helps!